# How to feed CNN with tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.data.dataset

I'm new with tensorflow. i'm trying to run the convolutional neural network for the binary classifitication between cats and dogs.

The data is structured this way: within a directory called *data*, there are two subdirectories: *test* and *train*. within each subdirectory there are two (sub)subdirectories called *cat* and *dog*.

What I'm trying to do is to use tf.data.Dataset to import the images and run the CNN to classify them.

Following the approach suggested in this ref (https://towardsdatascience.com/tf-data-creating-data-input-pipelines-2913461078e2) I could import the data as a Dataset object and separate it between image and label  (I'm not sure if it's right, I simply followed the approach proposed in the link above. By the way, is there any method to check if the process of separation and labeling is being correctly performed?):

```
from glob import glob
import tensorflow as tf

IMAGE_PATH_LIST = glob('/Users/josea/Desktop/Deep_Learning/cats_dogs/training/*/*.jpg')
DATA = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(IMAGE_PATH_LIST)

def load_images(path):
    
    image = tf.io.read_file(path)
    image = tf.io.decode_image(image)
    label = tf.strings.split(path, os.path.sep)[-2]
    return image, label

DATA= DATA.map(load_images)
```

I have a few questions: first, when I try to run the CNN (using the script below), it's given a error message "Input 0 of layer sequential_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 265, 3]".

Someone guess what am I doing wrong? Additionally, I'd like to check if the data is being correctly imported. Is there any good way to assess that?

my CNN attempt is shown below:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(DATA)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to batch your data:

```
DATA= DATA.map(load_images).batch(16)
```

You might face an error because your target seems to be a string. You can use a function like this to convert the path to a label:

```
def load_images(path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(path)
    image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (224, 224))

    parts = tf.strings.split(path, os.path.sep)
    bool_values = tf.equal(parts[-2], 'cats')
    indices = tf.cast(bool_values, tf.int32)
    return image, indices
```

Full example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.chdir('pictures')

files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('*jpg')

def load_images(path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(path)
    image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (224, 224))

    parts = tf.strings.split(path, os.path.sep)
    bool_values = tf.equal(parts[-2], 'cats')
    indices = tf.cast(bool_values, tf.int32)
    return image, indices

ds = files.map(load_images).batch(1)

next(iter(ds))
```

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[[[0.75831336, 0.8016107 , 0.72746104],
          [0.8311225 , 0.87016815, 0.79833937],
          [0.79161674, 0.8425971 , 0.77475995],
          ...,
          [0.08725347, 0.10316982, 0.11867575],
          [0.09943968, 0.1140053 , 0.1350136 ],
          [0.1064626 , 0.12102822, 0.14707875]]]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0])>)
```

Comment: Many thanks for you feedback. I've implemented this function you suggested but unfortunally now another error appears: "InvalidArgumentError: WhereOp : Unhandled input dimensions: 0". I've checking in other blogs and I found the suggestion of using _.eval()_ for tf.where (i.e., ``` indices = tf.where(bool_values).eval()). But another error message appears for this new approach: " Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`". Any guess?

Comment: Besides this error, I'm also a little confused on how to feed the CNN model with this dataset. Should I simply use ```model.fit(DATA)``` or more inputs are required to properly run the fitting?

Comment: I changed it. For your last question, yes.

Comment: @NicolasGervais Why have you used the value `16` in `.batch(16)`? What does it depend on?

Comment: You should use the largest batch size that fits on yout machine. For this code to work, you need at least 1.